# How to get the best polygon point pattern data in spatstat analysis in R

Tags: r, polygon, spatstat

I have a dataset of spatial locations [data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11bstg2760SoKVAH79rMJNmMxIyU966TU?usp=share_link). I want to do a point pattern analysis using the spatstat package in R using this data. I want the best polygon area for the analysis instead of the rectangle area. The code I have is

```
original_data = read.csv("/home/hudamoh/PhD_Project_Moh_Huda/Dataset_files/my_coordinates.csv")
plot(original_data$row, original_data$col)
```

which results in a plot that looks like this
[image: original_data]

Setting the data for point pattern data

```
point_pattern_data = ppp(original_data$row, original_data$col, c(0, 77), c(0, 116))
plot(point_pattern_data)
summary(point_pattern_data)
```

resulting in a plot that looks like this
[image: point_pattern]

#The observed data has considerably wide white spaces, which I want to remove for a better analysis area. Therefore, I want to make the point pattern a polygon instead of a rectangle. The vertices for the polygon are the pairs of (x,y) below to avoid white space as much as possible.

```
x = c(3,1,1,0.5,0.5,1,2,2.5,5.5, 16,21,28,26,72,74,76,75,74,63,58,52,47,40)
y = c(116,106,82.5,64,40,35,25,17.5,5,5,5,10,8,116,100,50,30,24,17,10,15,15,8)
```

I find these vertices above manually by considering the plot below (with the grid lines)

```
plot(original_data$row,original_data$col)
grid(nx = 40, ny = 25,
 lty = 2,      # Grid line type
 col = "gray", # Grid line color
 lwd = 2)      # Grid line width
```

[image: plot_grid]

So I want to make the point pattern polygon. The code is

```
my_data_poly = owin(poly = list(x = c(3,1,1,0.5,0.5,1,2,2.5,5.5, 16,21,28,26,72,74,76,75,74,63,58,52,47,40), y = c(116,106,82.5,64,40,35,25,17.5,5,5,5,10,8,116,100,50,30,24,17,10,15,15,8)))
plot(my_data_poly)
```

but it results in an error. The error is

[image: poly_error]

I fix it by

```
my_data_poly = owin(poly = list(x = c(116,106,82.5,64,40,35,25,17.5,5,5,5,10,8,116,100,50,30,24,17,10,15,15,8), y = c(3,1,1,0.5,0.5,1,2,2.5,5.5, 16,21,28,26,72,74,76,75,74,63,58,52,47,40)))
plot(my_data_poly)
```

It results in a plot
[image]

However, this is not what I want. How to get the observed area as a polygon in point pattern data analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don’t have access to the point data you read in from file, but if you just want to fix the polygonal window that is not a problem.

You need to traverse the vertices of your polygon sequentially and anti-clockwise.
The code connects the first point you give to the next etc. Your vertices are:

```r
library(spatstat)
x = c(3,1,1,0.5,0.5,1,2,2.5,5.5, 16,21,28,26,72,74,76,75,74,63,58,52,47,40)
y = c(116,106,82.5,64,40,35,25,17.5,5,5,5,10,8,116,100,50,30,24,17,10,15,15,8)
vert <- ppp(x, y, window = owin(c(0,80),c(0,120)))
plot.ppp(vert, main = "", show.window = FALSE, chars = NA)
text(vert)
```

[image]

Point number 13 is towards the bottom left and 14 in the top right, which gives the funny crossing in the polygon.
Moving the order around seems to help:

```r
xnew <- c(x[1:11], x[13:12], x[23:14])
ynew <- c(y[1:11], y[13:12], y[23:14])
p <- owin(poly = cbind(xnew, ynew))
plot(p, main = "")
```

[image]

It is unclear from your provided plot of the data that you really should apply point pattern analysis.
The main assumption underlying point process modelling as implemented in `spatstat`
is that the locations of events (points) are **random** and the process that
generated the random locations is of interest.
Your points seem to be on a grid and maybe you need another tool for your analysis.
Of course `spatstat` has a lot of functionality for simply handling and summarising data like this so you may still find useful tools in there.

Comment: Yes, this is partially what I want. The polygon window is exactly what I am looking for. I made a mistake in the order, as you found. After creating this polygon window (instead of a rectangle), I want to include all points (the coordinates are in the data mentioned on the link, i.e. x = original_data$row and y = original_data$col). So, the point pattern will be all these points inside the polygon. I still cannot find a way. Is there a way to include them inside the polygon?

Comment: You are correct, the locations of the events are randomly generated by the Poisson point process, but it will be the following analysis. My data is somehow complicated, so I want to do it step by step since I am new to this analysis and the spatstat as well

Comment: so basically in this code 'ppp(x, y, window = owin(c(0,80),c(0,120)))', my goal is that the x = original_data$row and y = original_data$col, and the window is the polygon

Comment: I found it now actually. `xnew <- c(x[1:11], x[13:12], x[23:14])
ynew <- c(y[1:11], y[13:12], y[23:14])
p <- owin(poly = cbind(xnew, ynew))
point_pattern = ppp(x = original_data$row and y = original_data$col, p)
plot(point_pattern, main = "Spatial point pattern")`

Answer (score 1):

This should be a reasonable solution to the problem.

```
require(sp)

poly = Polygon(
cbind(original_data$col,    
original_data$row)
    ))
```

This will create a polygon from your points. [You can use this document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/sp.pdf) to understand the `sp` package better

Comment: I tried this, and I got the polygon class. However, I cannot use function plot() directly to get the plot. Is it supposed to result in a polygon plot with all points as vertices? I am looking for a polygon with a number of vertices are as I mentioned (23) with vertices coordinates, as I mentioned. I am not familiar with the package but I will check